# Is this questionable SQL Update syntax with aliased table correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, alias

I saw this SQL Update statement in a trigger and am unsure if the update works accurately - based on looking at where the table alias is and the update table syntax.

The syntax doesn't give any error on execution, and updates the record correctly when executing on random samples on my test DB.

However, on a larger PROD DB with more records, is there a possibility that the update fails or skips altogether? There were reports that random records did not have the SAMPLE.ISCOMPOSITESAMPLE field set.

**Questionable syntax**

```
UPDATE SAMPLE SET 
    SAMPLE.SAMPLETYPE = (SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM SAMPLETYPE WHERE SAMPLETYPENO = C.SAMPLETYPENO),
    SAMPLE.ISCOMPOSITESAMPLE = (SELECT COMPOSITESAMPLE FROM SAMPLETYPE WHERE SAMPLETYPENO = C.SAMPLETYPENO)
FROM SAMPLE C 
INNER JOIN INSERTED T ON C.SAMPLENO = T.SAMPLENO
```

**Syntax I am familiar with (similar to above but intentionally not optimised for comparison)**

```
UPDATE C SET 
    SAMPLETYPE = (SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM SAMPLETYPE WHERE SAMPLETYPENO = C.SAMPLETYPENO),
    ISCOMPOSITESAMPLE = (SELECT COMPOSITESAMPLE FROM SAMPLETYPE WHERE SAMPLETYPENO = C.SAMPLETYPENO)
FROM SAMPLE C 
INNER JOIN INSERTED T ON C.SAMPLENO = T.SAMPLENO
```

Comment: The [grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is `UPDATE ... { table_alias | <object> | ... }`, where `<object>` is the unaliased object name. So yes, it will work.

Comment: Would a `SAMPLETYPENO` always exist or has it been removed inadvertently?

Comment: Hi Kami, yes, `SAMPLETYPENO` will always exist.

Comment: It may give you error sub query return more than one value  
If SAMPLETYPEND has more than one rows  in SAMPLETYPE table. 
Kindly use TOP 1 clause in both sub query.

(SELECT TOP 1 DESCRIPTION FROM SAMPLETYPE WHERE SAMPLETYPENO = C.SAMPLETYPENO)

Comment: Hi Jiken, noted. In this case, it's safe to use just SAMPLETYPENO as it is the primarykey of SAMPLETYPE and won't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct and will work.  However, there are two things that I would fix:

- The`UPDATE SAMPLE` does update the table whose alias is `C`.  This is documented as correct and something that really irks me, because aliases should be respected.  You should use the alias for the  update.
- The correlated subqueries are not using fully qualified column names.

So, using correlated subqueries, I would recommend:

```
UPDATE S 
    SET SAMPLETYPE = (SELECT ST.DESCRIPTION FROM SAMPLETYPE ST WHERE ST.SAMPLETYPENO = S.SAMPLETYPENO),
        ISCOMPOSITESAMPLE = (SELECT ST.COMPOSITESAMPLE FROM SAMPLETYPE ST WHERE ST.SAMPLETYPENO = S.SAMPLETYPENO)
FROM SAMPLE S INNER JOIN
     INSERTED I
     ON S.SAMPLENO = I.SAMPLENO ;
```

You can also write this -- probably more efficiently -- using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
UPDATE S 
    SET SAMPLETYPE = ST.DESCRIPTION,
        ISCOMPOSITESAMPLE = ST.COMPOSITESAMPLE
FROM SAMPLE S INNER JOIN
     INSERTED I
     ON S.SAMPLENO = I.SAMPLENO LEFT JOIN
     SAMPLETYPE ST 
     ON ST.SAMPLETYPENO = S.SAMPLETYPENO;
```